# ConfigurationErrorsException when trying to read from WinForms User Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have looked at previous iterations of this question before, but I was not able to solve my problem using those answers, so here goes...

Currently playing around with User settings in C# Windows Forms. This is my entire App.config file. It is generated by Visual Studio automatically, so prior to opening it to diagnose why this exception is being thrown, I did not touch it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="userSettings"    type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
          <section name="MyProject.General" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="MyProject.Settings.General" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <MyProject.General>
        <setting name="StoreName" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </MyProject.General>
      <MyProject.Settings.General>
          <setting name="StoreName" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
          <setting name="StoreAddress" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
          <setting name="StorePhone" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
          <setting name="ReqSettingsPassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value>False</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="SettingsPassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
          <setting name="ReqInventoryPassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value>False</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="InventoryPassword" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
          <setting name="ReqManagerOverride" serializeAs="String">
              <value>False</value>
          </setting>
          <setting name="ManagerOverride" serializeAs="String">
              <value />
          </setting>
      </MyProject.Settings.General>
  </userSettings>
```

Exception refers to this block of code:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
public string StoreName {
    get {
        return ((string)(this["StoreName"])); // * helper points to this line *
    }
    set {
            this["StoreName"] = value;
    }
}
```

And yes, the same error occurs when I give "StoreName" a default, non-null value.

From what I can tell, this file looks as it should (even has the `configSections` tag as the first child of `configuration`, etc.) - again, this is the file generated by Studio, so I did not mess with it prior to encountering this exception.

Comment: The only thing not clear is the definition for the section _MyProject.General_  missing from the config file. Did you try to remove that line?

Comment: @Steve Yes, but the exception was still happening even when that was there. I'll edit the question to include that section but the program still hits that error.

Comment: Agree with Steve.  See this often when namespaces have been changed, double check all your namespaces.  Namespaces in code need to match namespaces in generated code file need to match namespaces in config file.